Resolving disputed claims / reference or ownership conflicts via Youtube Content ID API
I am using YouTube Content ID API to automate some processes of resolving issues regarding disputed claims, Reference Overlapping, Ownership Conflicts, etc. I figured from this page that the resolution can be done manually from the Youtube Studio.
I've been looking at the Content ID API references and I figured that the APIs support displaying the on-going issues, histories of the issues, or what not but I could not find references for resolving them via API calls. I was mainly wondering if automating of resolving the issues is achievable via APIs. Perhaps the process was intended to solve the issues manually from the YouTube Studio? Thanks in advance.
I tried updating the assets, ownerships, references, etc to see if calling multiple APIs separately will eventually resolve the conflicts or disputed claims but I am too sure about what is actually expected on YouTube side for resolving issues.
